# What logic does the command "exec tail -n +3 $0" from grub2 config have?

Tags: shell, grub2, tail, exec

Creating custom menu entry, got stuck on this command:

```
exec tail -n +3 $0
```

Tried it in terminal, got weird result, cannot understand, what this command exactly does and why grub needs it. Could you explain, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tail -n +3` prints its input, starting at line 3 ([man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html)). `$0` is the name of the script in a shell script ([Bash special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)) and `exec` ([Bash builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec)) replaces the script with the command. You probably have something like this (like in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` on my system):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
foo
bar
```

When you run the script, it replaces itself with `tail` reading the script itself, so the rest of the script gets copied to its output.

I think grub has a bunch of scripts to create its config, they're probably executed as `grubscript.sh >> grub-config-file` or something to effect. The scripts could use any logic they need to produce the output, but the `exec tail` trick allows to just dump some fixed lines in the output without changing the logic the script is started with.

In addition to that magic incantation, Debian's `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` also includes a comment telling the user to

> Simply type the menu entries you want to add after this comment.

Comment: FWIW, squinting hard and assuming `#` is a comment character for grub anway, `#!/bin/cat` should work, too. (You'll have the shebang comment line in the output, though.)

Answer (score 12):

If you're talking about `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
$ cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
```

Then note that:

- this is a shell script, and is executed by `grub-mkconfig` to build GRUB configuration
- this file is supposed to be "an easy way to add custom menu entries" - you just type in exactly whatever GRUB configuration you want.

But this is a shell script, so usually you'd have to do something like `echo "menuentry ...."` etc. To avoid that, the `exec tail` magic is used. What does that do? `$0`, remember, is the name of the script as executed, so typically it would be `40_custom` (or `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, etc. depending on where and how it was run). So the script is essentially running `tail` on itself, but with `-n +3`, which tells `tail` to start from the third line.

What do you get if you output everything from the third line onwards in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`?

```
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
```

(And additionally whatever else you put below this.)

The `exec` part replaces the shell that's executing the script with `tail`, so effectively nothing further from the script is executed.

---

Running it in the terminal:

- `$0` is probably `bash` or something like that (it could be `/bin/bash`)
- and because of the `exec`, you're replacing the running shell with `tail -n+3 bash`
- and since you probably don't have a file named `bash` in your current directory, `tail` promptly quits.

So the end result is likely that your terminal session ended there.